# Can anyone tell me the problem with my code?

Tags: c

Everythings right except the output of the last part, I'm supposed to get this output https://i.stack.imgur.com/PRJMT.png but instead it got this https://i.stack.imgur.com/iZflq.png

Also heres my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    int n;
    printf("Enter the number of goal-scorers: ");    
    scanf("%d", &n);

    int ar[n];
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
        printf("Score of player #%d: ", i+1);
        scanf("%d", &ar[i]);
    }

    for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
        for(int j=i+1; j<n; j++){
            if(ar[i] <ar[j]){
                int temp = ar[j]; 
                ar[j] = ar[i];
                ar[i]; temp;
            }
        }
    }

    printf("\nHighest to lowest:\n");
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
        printf("Player #%d: %d\n",i+1, ar[i]);

    return;
}
```

Comment: Please do not post text as images. Please [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/71655273/edit) the post to add it as text.

Comment: Hi there, welcome to StackOverflow - before you post please read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. In particular, SO does not accept images of text input or output. Everything should be in text except for things that cannot be (e.g. images of a GUI)

Comment: You code is also not correctly formatted

Answer (score 1):

Found it!

`ar[i]; temp;`

But you want `ar[i] = temp;`

You enabled compiler warnings. What I don't get is why the warning for "statement has no effect" is not showing up.

Comment: The warning it did print doesn't need warning enabled.  Turning on warnings does find the bug: https://godbolt.org/z/WjbhqqYe6

Answer (score 0):

The possible solution may be like :

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct player {
    int no;
    int score;
};

int main() {
    int n;
    printf("Enter the number of goal-scorers: ");
    fflush(stdout);
    scanf("%d", &n);
    if (n <= 0)
        return 0 ;
    
    struct player players[n];
    for (int i = 0 ; i < n ; i++) {
        players[i].no = 1 + i;
        printf("Score of player #%d: ", players[i].no);
        fflush(stdout);
        scanf("%d", &players[i].score);
    }

    for (int i = 0 ; i < n ; i++) {
        for (int j = i + 1 ; j < n ; j++) {
            if (players[i].score < players[j].score) {
                struct player temp = players[j];
                players[j] = players[i];
                players[i] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
    
    printf("\nHighest to lowest:\n");
    for (int i = 0 ; i < n ; i++)
        printf("Player #%d: %d\n", players[i].no, players[i].score);

    return 0;
}
```